# batch script - how to compare current date with inside text file dates

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i have one text file which contains the dates, now i want to compare that dates with current date. if date match i need to perform some action other wise it would print else statement.

i tried the below codes but codes i'm not getting.
the variable contains all values but it taking last value for comparison.

codes:

```
for /f  %%i in (' MyFile.txt') do set ren=%%i
echo %ren%
if  %ren% == %date% goto same

goto notsame

:same
echo Dates the same, do some code here
exit /b

:notsame
echo Dates NOT the same, do some code here
exit /b
```

text file:

```
06/04/2017
16/09/2016
04/05/2016
```

Comment: How did you build the text file content? or asked differently: does the date format of the text file always comply with the format returned by `echo %date%`?

Comment: i gathered the text file information from sql based on my requirement and spooled to one particular directory...

Comment: Okay... so this means the date format derived from batch commands (`echo %date%`) may differ from the format used in the text file, is that true?; this makes everything more complicated; however, there are many questions here about retrieving system or file dates in standardised format; or you could also parse the `%date%` output and build a date value in the format of your text file programmatically, but this is locale-dependent...

Answer (score 0):

If the output of `echo %date:~-10%` on your PC is returned in the same format to those in the content of Myfile.txt then:

```
for /f %%i in (MyFile.txt) do if "%%i" equ "%date:~-10%" (call :same) else (call :notsame)
pause
exit /b
:same
echo Dates the same, do some code here
goto :eof
:notsame
echo Dates NOT the same, do some code here
goto :eof
```

Comment: I'm glad you received an answer that suited you. _It is helpful to the site, future and previous viewers, and also to motivate question responders that correct answeres are marked as such_.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q39533625.txt"
findstr /x "%date%" "%filename1%">nul

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 ECHO DATE %DATE% NOT found
) ELSE (
 ECHO DATE found:%date%
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `filename1` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q39533625.txt` containing your data for my testing.

`findstr /x` finds the current-date string in the file and sets `errorlevel` to 0 if found, non-zero otherwise. The `/x` means "exact match". the `>nul` suppresses `findstr`'s report-to-screen.

Comment: Hi Magoo..sorry the delay..i tried this but not worked...based on the system format i changed date as %date:~-10% though it's not worked.